# How to unlist a list of matrix elements and get combination of matrix as output instead of as vector in R

Tags: r, list

If I have a list called List A:

```
[[1]]
  [1] 11.000000  1.500000  2.666667  2.833333 10.000000  1.500000

[[2]]
  [1]  1.50  1.00  3.25  3.75 10.50  1.50

[[3]]
  [1] 10.5  1.5  1.5  1.5  5.0  5.5
```

How can I unlist List A in R and get the output as per below:

```
         [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]      [,6]
  [,1] 11.000000  1.500000  2.666667  2.833333 10.000000  1.500000
  [,2] 1.50       1.00      3.25      3.75     10.50      1.50
  [,3] 10.5       1.5       1.5       1.5      5.0        5.5
```

If I simply use unlist() it returns a vector

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `do.call` with `rbind`

```
do.call(rbind, A)
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the solution

Answer (score 4):

akrun's answer works well. An alternative method, which utilizes `unlist()`, is:

```
matrix(unlist(A), ncol=6, byrow=T)
```

This converts A into a vector, and then reorganizes it into a matrix with 6 columns, with the elements sorted by row.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the alternative method

Answer (score 2):

Also, `invoke` from `purrr`:

```
purrr::invoke(rbind, A)
```

`invoke` is just a wrapper around `do.call`.

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution